# NotimplementedException in System.Core.dll

Tags: c#, winforms, notimplementedexception

I am getting the error below in my code:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in >System.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: The method or operation is not implemented.

This happens when I try to set the datasource on my datagridview. The error occurs on the TextChanged event on a textbox where I am trying to filter the datagridview based on the input.

The code in the event is as below:

```
        IEnumerable<b2bHdr> filteredClaims = claims.Where(sc => sc.claimNumber.ToString().Contains(ntxtClaimNoSearch.Text));
        dgvHdr.DataSource = filteredClaims;
        dgvHdr.AutoResizeColumns();
        if (filteredClaims.Count() > 0)
        {
            dgvDtl.DataSource = filteredClaims;
            dgvDtl.DataMember = "b2bDetails";
            dgvDtl.AutoResizeColumns();
        }
        else
        {
            dgvDtl.DataSource = null;
        }
```

The Error occurs on the line `dgvDtl.DataSource = filteredClaims`

I have searched and can't find anything similar. I would appreciate any help with this.

The definition for b2bhdr is as below:

```
[Table(Name = "tbl_B2BHdr")]
public class b2bHdr
{
    private EntitySet<b2bDtl> _b2bDetails;
    public b2bHdr()
    {
        this._b2bDetails = new EntitySet<b2bDtl>(OnDtlAdded, OnDtlremoved);
    }

    private void OnDtlAdded(b2bDtl addedDtl) { addedDtl.hdrRecord = this; }
    private void OnDtlremoved(b2bDtl removedDtl) { removedDtl.hdrRecord = null; }


    [Association(ThisKey = "bhID", Storage = "_b2bDetails", OtherKey = "bhID")]
    public EntitySet<b2bDtl> b2bDetails
    {
        get { return this._b2bDetails; }
        set { this._b2bDetails.Assign(value); }
    }

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)] public Int32 bhID { get; set; }
    [Column] public Int32 cusID { get; set; }
    [Column] public int? rtHID { get; set; }
    [Column] public int? inhID { get; set; }
    [Column] public DateTime invoiceDate { get; set; }
    [Column] public DateTime? deliveryDate { get; set; }
    [Column] public Int32 referenceNumber { get; set; }
    [Column] public int? claimNumber { get; set; }
    [Column] public int? CreditInvoice { get; set; }
    [Column] public String CustomerName { get; set; }
    [Column] public Byte Type { get; set; }
    [Column] public Decimal InvoiceTotal { get; set; }
    [Column] public Decimal TaxTotal { get; set; }
    [Column] public Int32 TempID { get; set; }
    [Column] public String Notes { get; set; }
    [Column] public byte? status { get; set; }
    [Column] public Byte Deleted { get; set; }
```

Below is the debug information on the error:

```
    A first chance exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in System.Core.dll
   'sldatasys.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
   System.Transactions Critical: 0 : <TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>sldatasys.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.NotImplementedException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>The method or operation is not implemented.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Iterator`1.System.Collections.IEnumerator.Reset()
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListBindingHelper.GetFirstItemByEnumerable(IEnumerable enumerable)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListBindingHelper.GetListItemPropertiesByEnumerable(IEnumerable enumerable)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListBindingHelper.GetListItemProperties(Object list)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListBindingHelper.GetListItemProperties(Object list, PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindingContext.EnsureListManager(Object dataSource, String dataMember)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.SetDataConnection(Object dataSource, String dataMember)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.set_DataSource(Object value)
   at DairyProcessing.frmB2BView.btnClearClaimSearch_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Data\Projects\Stonelees Data Systems\Stonelees Data Systems\Forms\frmB2BView.cs:line 223
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&amp;amp; m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&amp;amp; msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at DairyProcessing.Program.Main() in c:\Data\Projects\Stonelees Data Systems\Stonelees Data Systems\Program.cs:line 19</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Iterator`1.System.Collections.IEnumerator.Reset()
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListBindingHelper.GetFirstItemByEnumerable(IEnumerable enumerable)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListBindingHelper.GetListItemPropertiesByEnumerable(IEnumerable enumerable)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListBindingHelper.GetListItemProperties(Object list)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListBindingHelper.GetListItemProperties(Object list, PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
   at System.Windows.Forms.BindingContext.EnsureListManager(Object dataSource, String dataMember)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.SetDataConnection(Object dataSource, String dataMember)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.set_DataSource(Object value)
   at DairyProcessing.frmB2BView.btnClearClaimSearch_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Data\Projects\Stonelees Data Systems\Stonelees Data Systems\Forms\frmB2BView.cs:line 223
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message&amp;amp; m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message&amp;amp; m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&amp;amp; msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at DairyProcessing.Program.Main() in c:\Data\Projects\Stonelees Data Systems\Stonelees Data Systems\Program.cs:line 19</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
   An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in System.Core.dll
   Additional information: The method or operation is not implemented.
```

Comment: What is `b2bHdr` and `claimNumber`? Can you show the class?

Comment: Most exception questions comes from misunderstanding of a call stack. Can you show us a full exception's call stack?

Comment: Also what is the "king of obfuscation" variable, `dgvDtl` (ie what type)?

Comment: b2bHdr is an linq class and claimnumber is an integer field

Comment: Sorry - more detail: dgvDetail is a datagridview which shows the details of the master record of b2bHdr

Comment: Can you add in the full stack trace?

Comment: I have edited the question to show the b2bHdr class

Comment: @DavidG: I am a relative newb: how do I get this

Comment: Is `Claims` an `IQueryable` and if so what is it querying against? I'm wondering if the linq provider may not have implemented something you are using there...

Comment: Does Linq2Sql implement `Contains`?

Comment: Chris: claims is an IEnumerable<b2bHdr> that is querying the database through the dataContext

Comment: @james33 When the exceptions happens in debug, you should be able to get lots of information about the full stack trace.

Comment: @DavidG I have added the debug information for when the error occurs

Comment: Obviously the error occurs when your query is materialized (`dgvDtl.DataSource = ...Where(...)` will go to the database). What are the underlying data source and provider? Is it MySQL? Did you try updating the MySQL Connector for .NET?

Comment: CodeCaster: Its MSSQL

Comment: Try calling `claims.Where(...).ToList()` to get a more useful stack trace.

Comment: The actual error is scrolled way off to the right.  Linq queries are forward only, a binding source needs to be able to rewind.  Use `dgvDtl.DataSource = filteredClaims.ToList();`

Comment: When I add .ToList it works. This however breaks the automatic filtering on the master and detail datagridviews. I will have to look at another way to go about this

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the prompt responses and suggestions